# on what basis relationship between tables are defined

Tags: sql-server

I have a question, if two tables in database are from different entities then how we define relationship between them. i mean can we use some foreign key or any thing to define relationship between them. or we have to create a third table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a design principle that states that a table either defines an entity or a relationship but not both. Therefore, use a third table to model the relationship between your two entities -- yes, even if it is 1-1 or 1-N -- noting that the relationship itself may have its own attributes.

Comment: i am confused, can you provide some link where i can get an example and understand thing .....

Comment: I do not know this principle and unfortunately can´t agree with it. There is no reason on why I cannot have the relationship (FK) on the same table when talking about a 1-N or 1-1 relationship.

Comment: I agree with tucaz. This sounds like it may be a principle/rule-of-thumb in certain ORM techniques.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: if by ORM you mean "object role modelling" then I suppose it is e.g. see http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html

Comment: @tucaz: "There is no reason on why I cannot have the relationship (FK) on the same table when talking about a ... 1-1 relationship" -- remind me: is Wife an attribute in the Husbands table or is Husband an attribute in the Wives table...? :)

Comment: @onedaywhen If it's a 1-1 relationship then the more precise way to implement this would be to each of them (wife/husband) have a column in their own table pointing to the other. However its only applicable without the use of FKs.

Comment: if two entities they have no relation between them, like one is some vehicle and one is human then how can i define relationship between them, i should make a third table or some foreign key should be define

Comment: @tucaz: "more precise" is in the eye of the beholder, it seems. You would model the same relationship (Marriages) twice in two different tables, thus violating another data modelling principle, being the principle of orthogonal design: "Within a given database, no two distinct base tables should have overlapping meanings." (http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/622312.htm)

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Is a `driver` an attribute of a car? No, my name doesn't show up on the registration details of the car I drive. Is `car` an attribute of a person? No, there's no mention of a car on my birth certificate. Therefore, use a separate table `Drivers` to model the relationship.

Comment: @onedaywhen: by ORM, I meant "Object-Relational Mapping" - I would recommend against using such techniques when designing a conventional relational schema.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of relationship you have. If it´s a 1-1 or 1-N then you will only add foreign key column on the respective table. If you need a N-N (aka N-M) you will need a third table.